# jenetics: Set EvolutionStream limit outside of stream()

Tags: java-stream, jenetics

There are several possibilities in [jenetics](https://jenetics.io/) to set termination limits to [`EvolutionStream`](https://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics/6.1/io/jenetics/engine/EvolutionStream.html), see the [documentation](https://jenetics.io/manual/manual-6.1.0.pdf#section.2.6).

The limits are usually applied directly on the `stream`, e.g.

```
Phenotype<IntegerGene,Double> result = engine.stream()
    .limit(Limits.bySteadyFitness(10))
    .collect(EvolutionResult.toBestPhenotype());
```

or

```
Phenotype<IntegerGene,Double> result = engine.stream()
    .limit(Limits.byFixedGeneration(10))
    .collect(EvolutionResult.toBestPhenotype());
```

or in combination, see [example](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/algorithms-genetic/src/main/java/com/baeldung/algorithms/ga/jenetics/TravelingSalesman.java):

```
Phenotype<IntegerGene,Double> result = engine.stream()
    .limit(Limits.bySteadyFitness(10))
    .limit(Limits.byFixedGeneration(10))
    .collect(EvolutionResult.toBestPhenotype());
```

In my optimization problem, I want to let the user decide which limits to assign to the problem. I do not know the limit setup in advance. It might be multiple limits. Therefore, I have to assign the limit types at runtime.

I tried to create a `EvolutionStream` object by

```
EvolutionStream<IntegerGene, Double> evolutionStream = engine.stream();
```

and assign the limits on the `evolutionStream`:

```
Stream<EvolutionResult<IntegerGene, Double>> limit = evolutionStream.limit(Limits.byFixedGeneration(10));
```

The result is a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), which does not know the `EvolutionStream` specific limit methods. Thus, I can not apply it in case multiple limits are defined. Trying to cast

```
evolutionStream = (EvolutionStream<IntegerGene, Double>)evolutionStream.limit(Limits.byFixedGeneration(10));
```

results in an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.stream.SliceOps$1 cannot be cast to class io.jenetics.engine.EvolutionStream (java.util.stream.SliceOps$1 is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; io.jenetics.engine.EvolutionStream is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

So, is there a way to properly apply multiple limits outside the stream builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`EvolutionStream.limit(Predicate)`](https://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics/io/jenetics/engine/EvolutionStream.html#limit(java.util.function.Predicate)) method does return an `EvolutionStream`.

```
EvolutionStream<IntegerGene, Double> stream = engine.stream();
stream = stream
    .limit(Limits.byFixedGeneration(10))
    .limit(Limits.bySteadyFitness(5))
    .limit(Limits.byExecutionTime(Duration.ofMillis(100)));
```

So your given examples look good and should work. But the `EvolutionStream.limit(Predicate)` method is the *only* method which gives you back an `EvolutionStream`.

An alternative would be that your method, which initializes the `EvolutionStream`, takes the `Predicate`s from outside.

```
@SafeVarargs
static EvolutionStream<IntegerGene, Double>
newStream(final Predicate<? super EvolutionResult<IntegerGene, Double>>... limits) {
    final Engine<IntegerGene, Double> engine = Engine
        .builder(a -> a.gene().allele().doubleValue(), IntegerChromosome.of(0, 100))
        .build();

    EvolutionStream<IntegerGene, Double> stream = engine.stream();
    for (var limit : limits) {
        stream = stream.limit(limit);
    }

    return stream;
}    
    
final var stream = newStream(
    Limits.byFixedGeneration(100),
    Limits.byExecutionTime(Duration.ofMillis(1000)),
    Limits.bySteadyFitness(10)
);
```

Comment: Thanks. As you said, it worked. Some code cleanup did the trick